# ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: a 'LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Float64, Matrix{Float64}}' is not a table; see `?Tables.table`

Tags: dataframe, julia

```
function price_zones(a::Array{Float64,2})
    v_temp = vec(convert(Array, mapcols!(count_unique, DataFrame(transpose(a[:,1:3])))))
    df = DataFrame(OnePriceZone = sum(v_temp .== 1),
                   TwoPriceZones = sum(v_temp .== 2),
                   ThreePriceZones = sum(v_temp .== 3))
    return df
end
```

This is giving an error LoadError: ArgumentError: a 'LinearAlgebra.Transpose{Float64, Matrix{Float64}}' is not a table; see `?Tables.table` for ways to treat an AbstractVecOrMat as a table

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass the `:auto` positional argument to the `DataFrame` constructor to make it work:

   ```
   julia> using DataFrames

   julia> foo = [1 2;3 4]
   2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
    1  2
    3  4

   julia> DataFrame(foo', :auto)
   2×2 DataFrame
    Row │ x1     x2
        │ Int64  Int64
   ─────┼──────────────
      1 │     1      3
      2 │     2      4
   # Note that foo' and transpose(foo) can be used interchangeably
   ```
2. Since you declared `a` as a Matrix, then you can use `permutedims` without any extra keyword argument to perform transposition and make it suitable for the `DataFrame` constructor by passing the `:auto` positional argument to the `DataFrame` constructor:

   ```
   julia> DataFrame(permutedims(foo), :auto)
   2×2 DataFrame
    Row │ x1     x2
        │ Int64  Int64
   ─────┼──────────────
      1 │     1      3
      2 │     2      4
   ```

In summary, you can replace `DataFrame(transpose(a[:,1:3]))` in your code with one of the following:

- `DataFrame(permutedims(a[:,1:3]), :auto)`
- `DataFrame(a[:,1:3]', :auto)`
- `DataFrame(transpose(a[:,1:3]), :auto)`

## Aditional note

If you want to specify the column names in the DataFrame construction, you can replace `:auto` with `["Column1", "Column2", "Column3"]` or `[:Column1, :Column2, :Column3]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. But it Still gives an error now.

Comment: ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type 
  DataFrame to an object of type 
  Array

Comment: The new error is because of another part of the code. Make sure to include enough details and explain what you want to do and provide a minimal reproducible example. Otherwise, I can't help further.

Comment: price_zones_temp = vec(convert(Array,price_zones(d_1_nodal_price)))

Comment: d_1_nodal_price= Matrix(DataFrame(CSV.File(string("df_d_1_nodal_price.csv"))))

Comment: function count_unique(v::Array{Float64,1})
    s = length(unique(v))
    return s
end